# Firestore: userId rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**I cannot get this firestore rule to work.**

I want to write/read to `user-read-only/USER-ID-HERE/business/settings`

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /user-read-only/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;

      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I continue to get the message

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I have tried many different approaches with the simulator and they are all successful, but I can’t repro from my app.

---

- Does anything look incorrect above?
- Can the above be simplified? I would like the user to be able to control everything beyond `{userId}`
- How do I know if `request.auth.uid` and `userId` are populating properly?

---

This works

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update following your comment "The intent is to expand the rule so that anything beyond `{userId}` can be managed by the user":

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /user-read-only/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;

    }
  }
}
```

**Just note that the `create` rule (*copied from your question*) allows any authenticated user to write under any `{userId}` folder.**

---

(On the opposite if you just want to declare a rule for `business/settings` sub-collection and doc) the following should do the trick:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /user-read-only/{userId}/business/settings {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;

    }
  }
}
```

In order to be sure that `userId` is populated properly, you could add it as a field to the document when created and check in the rules for `create` that it is correct, as follows:

`allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId`;

On the other hand, Firebase Auth will automatically ensure that `request.auth.uid` is correctly populated.

Finally, you may watch this very good video from the Firebase team about Security Rules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw

---

Here is the HTML page used for testing. Just change the value of `userId` with the different user's ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.3/firebase.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: 'xxxxx',
        authDomain: 'xxxxx',
        databaseURL: 'xxxxx',
        projectId: 'xxxxx'
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);

      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword('xxxxxx@gmail.com', 'yyyyyyy')
        .then(userCredential => {

          const userId = userCredential.user.uid;
          // Replace with another userId to test
          //e.g. const userId = 'l5Wk7UQGRCkdu1OILxHG6MksUUn2';

          firebase
            .firestore()
            .doc('user-read-only/' + userId + '/business/settings4')
            .set({ tempo: 'aaaaaaa' })
            .then(() => {
              return firebase
                .firestore()
                .doc(
                  'user-read-only/' + userId + '/testC/1/collec/2'
                )
                .get();
            })
            .then(function(doc) {
              if (doc.exists) {
                console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
              } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log('No such document!');
              }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log('Error getting document:', error);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, this doesn't work. ` FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: Also, I didn’t communicate it clearly enough, but the intent is to expand the rule so that anything beyond `{userId}` can be managed by the user.

Comment: When you try to write or read? I've thoroughly checked it and it seemed to work for me.

Comment: I confirm that following my tests it works as expected (unless there is an obvious error I don't see!! ;-)). I've updated the answer based on your comment "the intent is to expand the rule so that anything beyond `{userId}` can be managed by the user"

Comment: Yah, I’m sure I’m doing something wrong somewhere, just need to figure out where! :)

Comment: I believe so. I am able to get a value at `auth.user.uid`. `firebase.firestore().collection('user-read-only').doc(auth.user.uid)`

Comment: I've added to the answer the HTML page that I used to test. Just change the value of `userId` as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Did you deploy security rules?

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#deploying_rules

> Before you can start using Cloud Firestore from your mobile app, you will need to deploy security rules. You can deploy rules in the Firebase console or using the Firebase CLI.

Did you have loggedin using Firebase Authentication?

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

> If your app uses Firebase Authentication, the request.auth variable contains the authentication information for the client requesting data. For more information about request.auth, see the reference documentation.

How do you call Firestore method?

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Like this?

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
var docRef = db.doc(`user-read-only/${userId}/business/settings`);

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

I think you should change structure data.

A structure data should be like `db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')`.

(`Collections->doc->SubCollections->SubDoc->SubSubCollections->SubSubDoc`)

So {userId} should be docId. Not collections.

The security rules should be the this.

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;

      match /settings/{setting} {
        allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }
  }
}
```

The settings collection ref is `db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('settings')`.

If does not work then you should try basic rule sets.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have it setup that way

Comment: I think you should change structure data or try basic rule sets. Best.